# Single sign on, using Firebase auth to different Angular apps

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

We use Firebase to authenticate users on our site. Once authenticated, we want users to select and run different Angular apps written by our team, and hosted on different Firebase hosted sites. Since we have all the Firebase user information from their original login, how can we share that with the other apps, so they can be logged into Firebase too as the same user? Don't want to send username/passwords around, prefer to share the "accessToken" if possible, then reauthenticate the user within each Angular app.